# Count string length and remove characters if a certain length

Tags: r, regex, string, count

I have used the following code to reduce the length of postcodes, to postcode sectors:

```
postcode <- substring(postcode, 1, nchar(scot.population$Postcode)-2 )
```

Unfortunately some strings are left with an extra character and therefore I need to remove it. I have this data currently:

```
postcode <- c("AB123L", "AB125Y", "AB140L")
```

How do I count those strings that have 7 characters and remove the final letter?

Comment: Try `sub("^(.{6}).$", "\\1", "postcode)` or `sub("^([[:alnum:]]{6})[[:alnum:]]$", "\\1", "postcode)` (to remove the final char if the length is 7).

Comment: Probably the easiest thing is to use `substr`: `substr(postcode, 1, 6)`; this takes the first 6 characters of each string

Comment: But the above one does not check if the string length is 7, and the type of characters (not sure if that is important).

Comment: Are we trying to clean up [postcodes](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/283357/ILRSpecification2013_14Appendix_C_Dec2012_v1.pdf), see page 2. If we are trying to get outcode, then we need to know where incode starts and stops, then simple `substr` should work. Could you give us `raw` input postcode?

Comment: I believe this should do it: `ifelse(nchar(postcode) == 7, substring(postcode, 1, 6), postcode)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is not important; if a string is not 7 character long but 6, this will still return a six character value

Comment: @cimentadaj no need to use ifelse imo; see my previous comments

Comment: True, thanks for the explanation @ProcrastinatusMaximus

Comment: Please add sample postcodes from `scot.population$Postcode` and expected output.